# Installing Webpack in Prestashop 1.7 : package.json => no such file

Tags: npm, prestashop-1.7

I need to edit the theme.css in a fresh install of Prestashop 1.7, for this I need to use Webpack to compile styles and javascript as described [here](http://developers.prestashop.com/themes/assets/index.html#about-webpack).

But when I run **npm install**, I get this error message :

```
prestashop/themes/classic/_dev$ sudo npm install
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/html/prestashop/themes/classic/_dev/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/html/prestashop/themes/classic/_dev/package.json'
npm WARN _dev No description
npm WARN _dev No repository field.
npm WARN _dev No README data
npm WARN _dev No license field.
```

For some reason, I have the file package-lock.json in my folder and not package-lock.json. My version of npm is 5.4.2.

How should I fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to:

1. Download `package.json` from classic theme github repository:
   https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/tree/1.7.1.x/themes/classic/_dev
2. Copy it to `_dev` folder.
3. Run `npm install`.